# injecting modules with angular

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to separate my app into different modules and inject the factories in the controllers 
I think this is very close just need help finding the gap. Any help is appreciated.

index.html

```
<body ng:app='module_1'>
<script src="js/scripts/module_1.js'"></script>
<script src="js/scripts/dD/module_2.js"></script>
<script src="js/scripts/dD/module_3.js"></script>
```

module_1.js

```
angular.module('module_1', ['ngCookies','module_2','module_3'])
```

module_2.js

```
angular.module('module_2', [])
  .factory('module_2_Fact', ['$scope', function() {

      function test () {
          return "test"
      }

      return {
         test:test
      }


}]);
```

module_3.js

```
angular.module('module_3', ['module_2'])

    .controller('module_3_Ctrl', ['$scope', function(module_2_Fact) {

        console.log(module_2_Fact.test); // == > undefined 

    }]);
```

module_2_Fact.test returns Cannot read property 'test' of undefined

it seems like module_3 can not find module_2

Comment: I would think that `module_2` would crash due to the `test` variable not being defined

Comment: You aren't injecting properly into the controller function of module_3. You specified `$scope` and didn't use it, and didn't specify `module_2_Fact`

Comment: yes but I am trying to find out why, In theory all services/  factories should be accessible through the module in this pattern

Comment: if you do not inject $scope 
    
.controller('module_3_Ctrl', ['module_2_Fact', function 

$scope becomes undefined

unknown provider: $scopeProvider <- $scope <- dealsDetailsFact

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please remove '`$scope`' from your `module_2_Fact`

```js
angular.module('module_1', ['module_2', 'module_3']).controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, module_2_Fact) {

  $scope.name = "Charlie";
  console.log(module_2_Fact.test)
  $scope.data = module_2_Fact.test();


})

angular.module('module_2', [])
  .factory('module_2_Fact', [
    function() {

      function test() {
        return {
          test: "that's my test"
        }
      }

      return {
        test: test
      }


    }
  ]);

angular.module('module_3', ['module_2'])

.controller('module_3_Ctrl', ['$scope',
  function(module_2_Fact) {

    console.log(module_2_Fact.test); // == > undefined 

  }
]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="module_1">



  <div ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <p>Hello {{name}}!</p>
    <p>{{data| json}}</p>
  </div>
```

Comment: I see thanks for the correction it is working  when module_2 is injected into module_1 all is well.

However it is not working when module_2 is injected into module_3

http://plnkr.co/edit/DnxZNELKiW9hyjIVS3Ty?p=preview

as the original issue pointed out

Comment: @user1675557 please see here http://plnkr.co/edit/3Qa6jIunMAUojKzsFwV1?p=preview you need to add ng-app="module_3" to your view

Comment: is this the only way ?? none of the tutorials that use this technique have more then one ng:app

Comment: Im not sure if adding ng:app to the view is needed.

http://plnkr.co/edit/3Qa6jIunMAUojKzsFwV1?p=preview

when it is removed from the view there is no change